# How can i use current CoroutineScope for `CoroutineScope.async` from suspend function?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

If i want to use current `CoroutineScope` from other suspend functions,

how can i retrieve it?

The codes below are I've tried.

```
fun main() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val result = getTitleAndLabel() // suspend function
    // doSomthing with result
}
```

```
#Case1
// Ambiguous coroutineContext due to CoroutineScope receiver of suspend function
suspend fun CoroutineScope.getTitleAndLabel() {
    val titleDeferred = async { getTitle() }
    val labelDeferred = async { getLabel() }
    val (title, label) = listOf(titleDeferred, labelDeferred).awaitAll()
    return Pair(title, label)
}
```

```
#Case2
// It makes another CoroutineScope
suspend fun getTitleAndLabel() = coroutineScope {
    val titleDeferred = async { getTitle() }
    val labelDeferred = async { getLabel() }
    val (title, label) = listOf(titleDeferred, labelDeferred).awaitAll()
    return Pair(title, label)
}
```

```
#Case3
// No need to do ContextSwitching
suspend fun getTitleAndLabel() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val titleDeferred = async { getTitle() }
    val labelDeferred = async { getLabel() }
    val (title, label) = listOf(titleDeferred, labelDeferred).awaitAll()
    return Pair(title, label)
}
```

```
#Case4
// Passing CoroutineScope as an argument?
suspend fun getTitleAndLabel(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {
    val titleDeferred = coroutineScope.async { getTitle() }
    val labelDeferred = coroutineScope.async { getLabel() }
    val (title, label) = listOf(titleDeferred, labelDeferred).awaitAll()
    return Pair(title, label)
}
```

#Case1, #Case2, #Case3, #Case4

Comment: Your "case 2" is the correct implementation. You can see it in the docs here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#structured-concurrency-with-async

Comment: @Sam I am not sure that "case 2" match the requirement to use "current" coroutine scope. Seems like OP wants to use specific scope to call 'async/await'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I challenge the need to use the exact same CoroutineScope as the parent coroutine.

Your Case #2 fits the example you have set up. It creates a new scope, true, but it is a scope that inherits the parent coroutine's CoroutineContext, so it will get cancelled if the parent gets cancelled. You can loosely think of it as a *child* coroutine scope, although there isn't in practice any hierarchy of scopes or contexts.

The advantage of Case #2 over Case #4 (aside from the obvious easier usage and avoidance of accidentally passing a different scope than the parent is being called in), is that it encapsulates the behavior. If either of your async tasks fails, it automatically cancels the other (to avoid wasting time and resources), before it throws to the caller of this suspend function. With Case #4, this behavior will depend on whether the passed CoroutineScope has a SupervisorJob or not. And if it doesn't have a SupervisorJob, then these children will cause all coroutines from that scope to be cancelled. It is usually preferred to encapsulate, to choose your behavior from within this suspend function.

If your aysnc child coroutines have important side effects that should run even if their siblings fail, you can replace `coroutineScope { }` with `supervisorScope { }`. Then they will all run to completion regardless of their siblings' success, and the first exception thrown will be rethrown to the caller of the suspend function after they have all finished.

Incidentally, `withContext`, which you use in Case #3 is basically the same thing as `coroutineScope` except that it gives you an opportunity to also override some parameters of the inherited CoroutineContext. It runs its contents in another CoroutineScope, just like `coroutineScope { }` does.